# Can I build Google Closure projects in Eclipse while building with Plovr?

Tags: eclipse, google-closure, plovr

I want to use an IDE to develop my application that uses the Google Closure javascript library. I am currently editing all my javascript files in vim and compiling using Plovr.

However, I would like to harness the power of an IDE that can check for errors and show types to me as I develop. Can I use Eclipse to develop applications that use Google Closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a few threads on the Closure Library discussion group about using IDEs to develop Closure web apps such as this one: ***[IDE for use with google closure?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/closure-library-discuss/9X7oKXwX-lA)***

I use IntelliJ IDEA combined with plovr to develop Closure apps, but using Eclipse should be a very similar experience. As I edit code in Intellij, I often have the plovr server running so that I can quickly see how code changes look in the app just by refreshing the browser.

Plovr author Michael Bolin shared some insight into his development process in response to the stackoverflow question ***[Getting closure-compiler and Node.js to play nice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358980/1164465)***.