# Is the Google Closure Compiler Not Meant for Backend NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-closure-compiler

Is there any point to running backend node.js code through the Google Closure Compiler since noone has to download your code in a browser? Do you get non-trivial performance gains from the GCC?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287597/getting-closure-compiler-and-node-js-to-play-nice and https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3

Comment: What you meant by noone has to download your code in a browser ?Closure compiler will do minification and it will remove the dead code ,but you need the code to be available in the browser as a minified code ,It will also little bit increase the performance of file loading

Comment: @krishnakumarsekar The question is in regards to using closure-compiler with a nodejs server. There is no browser involved here. It's a completely different use case.